# What's the formula to select a range excluding a sub-range?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I want to say A1:A60 excluding A20:A30. Is there a minus operator for use with ranges, in Google Sheets?

I know that you can take the union of two ranges, like {A1:A19;A31:A60}. I would like to know if there's an operator that excludes one range from another.

Comment: Is it always the same range to exclude or is there  some conditions  within the range that we can use to define the rule for exclusion?

Comment: Good question. I think you have to get tricky as I don't think there's a SUBTRACT or EXCEPT function

Comment: For now, it's always the same range, @AuriellePerlmann , to keep it simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the following formula it is possible to exclude a certain range:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({ROW(A1:A60), A1:A60}, "SELECT Col2 WHERE Col1<20 OR Col1>30"))
```

Comment: While this is so complex as to not be worth it, it looks like Sheets doesn't support anything better, so I've accepted this answer.

Comment: What do `Col1` & `Col2` refer to?

Comment: @giraldi _Col1_ is pointing to the first range, being the rows. _Col2_ point towards the second range. See help: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276

Answer (score 1):

This is bit better:

```
=FILTER(A1:A20,A1:A20 > E1)
```

Comment: what is the value of E1, how does this work?